# compare string from database and from c#

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, datagrid

If I have a query

```
var query = from c in ds.Prices
            select c;
dataGridControl1.AutoCreateColumns = true;
dataGridControl1.ItemsSource = query;
```

datagrid show all data from table(`ds = new DataSet()). But when I add condition

```
var query = from c in ds.Prices
            where c.idsticker.Equals("GOOG")
            select c;
dataGridControl1.AutoCreateColumns = true;
dataGridControl1.ItemsSource = query;
```

datagrid is empty. But value GOOG exists in table(`idsticker varchar(10)` in sql server). When I compare int values(for example condition is `where c.prices > 660`) it works normal.

What is wrong?

Comment: Have you checked to see if there is a record which has a null idsticker? Or perhaps, the entry with "GOOG" is really "G00G".

Comment: You may have hidden character or a space. For a test, copy the text from the field from the database, the one with GOOG. And then do your code comparison. Another method is to use the SQL Manager, and execute a simple query.

Comment: there are no such records. all records are from .csv file

Comment: @user1432980, I understand the data may come from csv but when you transfer data from any file to a database, a space may be generated due to quirks in data transfers or buffer copies, like in HTML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All I can think of is to apply a Trim() to it, and possibly ToUpper() to see if one or both of those makes any difference.

```
var query = from c in ds.Prices 
            where c.idsticker.Trim().ToUpper().Equals("GOOG") 
            select c; 
dataGridControl1.AutoCreateColumns = true; 
dataGridControl1.ItemsSource = query;
```

Beyond that, try executing the same query using SQL against your database.

```
select * from prices where idsticker = 'GOOG'
```

Comment: @user1432980, no, trim itself wasn't the problem, nor additional methods mentioned by Chris. Look what those functions do at least......

Comment: I mean problem was with spaces